# Rails how to set up stupid-table-plugin on application?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, sorting, jquery-plugins

Hi guys I've just tried to use stupid-table-plugin on my rails app.

http://joequery.github.io/Stupid-Table-Plugin/

So, I first downloaded Zip file from above site.

Among several examples, I was trying to test with 'basic.html'

Here is what I tried and it is not working.

1. I changed 'basic.html' to 'basic.html.erb' to put it on my rails view folder(Also made a route for this)
2. from the downloaded file, I collected all the javascript related files and put it below '/app/assets/javascripts',(stupitable.js , stupitable.min.js)

but it doesn't work.

basic.html.erb looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Stupid jQuery table sort</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="stupidtable.js?dev"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#simpleTable").stupidtable();
    });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border: 1px solid #999;
    }
    th {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    th[data-sort]{
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    tr.awesome{
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Stupid jQuery table sort!</h1>

  <p>This example shows how a sortable table can be implemented with very little configuration. Simply specify the data type on a <code>&lt;th&gt;</code> element using the <code>data-sort</code> attribute, and the plugin handles the rest.</p>

  <table id="simpletable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-sort="int">int</th>
        <th data-sort="float">float</th>
        <th data-sort="string">string</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>-.18</td>
        <td>banana</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="awesome">
        <td>95</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>coke</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>-152.5</td>
        <td>apple</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>-53</td>
        <td>88.5</td>
        <td>zebra</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>195</td>
        <td>-858</td>
        <td>orange</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

and my error on my console

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
basic:38
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).stupidtable is not a function

I feel there's a problem with my javascript files but I have no idea how to set up.

Thank you! Please help me

Answer (score 0):

$("#simpleTable").stupidtable(); 
should be 
$("#simpletable").stupidtable();

Comment: Thank you for you comment. but I tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work.  "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/stupidtable.js?dev" is the error message I get from my console. I feel there is a problem with my <script src="stupidtable.js?dev"></script>

Comment: Okay, are you adding this source line manually? '/stupidtable.js?dev'. You should add '//= require_tree .' in your application.js (It will load all javascript in the assets folder.